# Cannot startup tomcat5.5 on debian

Tags: tomcat, debian

I installed tomcat5.5 on debian by using the command apt-get install tomcat5.5. However, when I run /etc/init.d/tomcat5.5 start, nothing is happening. Then I looked into the file /var/log/syslog and I see the following output:

```
jsvc.exec[8278]: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap
jsvc.exec[8278]: #011at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
jsvc.exec[8278]: #011at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
jsvc.exec[8278]: #011at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
jsvc.exec[8278]: #011at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
jsvc.exec[8278]: #011at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
jsvc.exec[8278]: #011at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
jsvc.exec[8278]: #011at org.apache.commons.daemon.support.DaemonLoader.load(DaemonLoader.java:107)
jsvc.exec[8278]: Cannot load daemon
```

I'm looking already for the solution for many many days and I hope that someone here also had once the same problem and can point me towards the solution :). Some people say that you need commons-logging.jar. However, I don't know at all where to put that .jar..

Thx for any help in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came across similar bug in tomcat 5.5 long time back which was fixed in subsequent release...so either use 6.x or 7.x ...or patch the 5.5 version

Answer (score 2):

if you're missing JARs on start-up, put them in the /server/lib directory.  Keep adding JARs as required by `ClassNotFoundExceptions` demand until they stop.

I'd question why you're using Tomcat 5.5 when 6.x and 7.x are available.  Is there a particular reason?

Comment: I'm using tomcat5.5 because aptitude provides only tomcat5.5. Is tomcat6 maybe unstable on debian?

Comment: @mkn - tomcat5.5 is only in oldstable (i.e. lenny) in Debian. tomcat6 is in stable (squeeze). I'd highly recommend upgrading because the end of security support for oldstable is fast approaching.

Comment: thx for helping me. I installed tomcat7 and it runs perfectly